# Small order examples of non-nilpotent finite groups in which every minimal normal subgroup intersects the center nontrivially

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, linear-groups

I know that $p$-groups have the property, and all nilpotent groups also do. I wanted to have some non-nilpotent examples. Then [I checked quasisimple groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3642927/517681), and found every proper normal subgroups of a quasisimple is contained in the center.

Quasisimple group ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ would be an example I want, when $q>3$ is an odd. For an odd $q>3$, the center of ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ is of order 2 and that makes ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ a non-simple quasisimple group with the property held; otherwise, for an even $q>3$, ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ has trivial center. Although ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ is not quasisimple, ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ also holds the property and is hopefully the example of the smallest order. **My question is:** How to prove ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ is the example of the smallest order? What are other kinds of groups that may be examples?

Thank you, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: $SL(2,3)$ is indeed the smallest non-nilpotent example, but I don't know of an easy way to prove this without considering many cases (or using a computer).

Comment: @verret thanks. Is there any reference about that?

Comment: No, I just checked in magma right now.

Comment: @verret I also want to try it in magma, but I’m totally new. Can it be realized in the [free web page version](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)? If it can, could you please help me with the code? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, try this for  a start: for n in [1..64] do
for i in [1..NumberOfSmallGroups(n)] do
G:=SmallGroup(n,i);
if not IsNilpotent(G) and Socle(G) eq (Center(G) meet Socle(G)) then
[n,i];
end if;
end for;
end for;

Comment: @verret Thanks. It’s very kind of you to give the helpful comments. It gives [24,3]. I think ```Smallgroup(24,3)``` stands for ${\rm SL}(2,3)$. Is there a corresponding list that I can refer to?

Comment: You can for example run "IsIsomorphic(SL(2,3),SmallGroup(24,3));" or you can check https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way to check that $\mathrm{SL}_2(3)$ has the desired property using the computer algebra system GAP:

```
grps:=AllSmallGroups([1..24],IsNilpotentGroup,false);; 
list:=Filtered(grps,x->Order(Center(x))>1);  

for g in list do
Print(StructureDescription(g),"  ",IsSubgroup(Center(g),Socle(g)),"\n");
od;

C3 : C4  false
D12  false
C3 x S3  false
C5 : C4  false
D20  false
C3 : C8  false
SL(2,3)  true
C3 : Q8  false
C4 x S3  false
D24  false
C2 x (C3 : C4)  false
(C6 x C2) : C2  false
C2 x A4  false
C2 x C2 x S3  false
```

Comment: Thanks. What does it mean by ```C3:C4 ```?

Comment: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X87BF1B887C91CA2E

Comment: very helpful : )